# Significati e usi di "manipolatore/trice", "manipolante", "manipolatorio/a", "manipolativo/a"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Dal verbo "manipolare" discendono:

1. [manipolatore,
   manipolatrice](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manipolatore/),
   s.m. e f.: «Chi manipola»
2. manipolante, part. pres. di manipolare: «che manipola»
3. [manipolatorio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manipolatorio/), agg.: «Che riguarda la manipolazione, che comporta una manipolazione, che consiste in una manipolazione»
4. [manipolativo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manipolativo/), agg.: «Relativo alla manipolazione, che serve a manipolare»

Che confusione!

Il primo è un sostantivo, ma si può usare come aggettivo? Un manipolatore è una "persona manipolatrice"? O piuttosto una "persona manipolante"? Certo non una "persona manipolatoria"! Ma forse una "persona manipolativa", con l'intenzionale attitudine a manipolare?

Un comportamento può essere manipolatorio/manipolativo? O sarebbe meglio usare questi due termini solo in giurisprudenza ("sentenze manipolatorie/manipolative") o forse in campo tecnico? Non sarebbe meglio dire un "comportamento manipolante"? Certo "un comportamento manipolatore" non mi suona molto bene. E un "comportamento manipolatorio/manipolativo" è lo stesso che un "comportamento manipolante"?

Il participio presente, "manipolante", non ha neanche una sua definizione nella Treccani né, mi pare, altrove. Sembra da Google che sia anche [scarsamente utilizzato](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manipolatore%2Cmanipolatrice%2Cmanipolante%2Cmanipolatorio%2Cmanipolatoria%2Cmanipolativo%2Cmanipolativa&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmanipolatore%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmanipolatore%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BManipolatore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolatrice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolatorio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolatoria%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolativo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanipolativa%3B%2Cc0).

Ad ogni modo, espongo di seguito il mio orientamento.

Per persone:

1. "persona manipolatrice" (che adotta comportamenti che manipolano)? Incerto
2. "persona manipolante" (che adotta comportamenti che manipolano)? Sì, ma senza fonte
3. "persona manipolatoria" (che adotta comportamenti che manipolano)? No
4. "persona manipolativa" (con l'intenzionale attitudine a manipolare)? Sì

Per comportamenti:

1. "comportamento manipolatore" (che manipola)? Incerto
2. "comportamento manipolante" (che manipola)? Sì, ma senza fonte
3. "comportamento manipolatorio" (che comporta manipolazione)? Sì
4. "comportamento manipolativo" (che serve a manipolare)? Sì

Comment: Da dove hai preso `manipolante`? Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/manipolante/) non lo elenca... comunque l'uso del `che` mi farebbe pensare che *non* può essere usato per le persone.

Comment: "manipolante" è il partecipio presente del verbo "manipolare": il problema è proprio che nessuno lo cita come aggettivo a sé stante (per questo ho scritto che è senza fonte). Il [_che_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/che1/) è qui solo pronome relativo, «persona manipolante ---> persona _che_ manipola».

Answer (score 1):

Cerco di rispondere per ordine una domanda alla volta, vediamo se riusciamo a fare un po' di chiarezza :)

> Il primo è un sostantivo, ma si può usare come aggettivo?

Se vuoi essere preciso, no (per lo meno, in tutti i vocabolari che ho controllato non viene menzionato come aggettivo). Sempre per precisione, in realtà sarebbe anche meglio **non** usarlo come aggettivo, siccome la definizione della parola è "colui che manipola", quindi una persona che manipola. Dire "un uomo manipolatore" significherebbe dire "un uomo che è un uomo che manipola".

> Un manipolatore è una "persona manipolatrice"? O piuttosto una
>   "persona manipolante"? Certo non una "persona manipolatoria"! Ma forse una "persona manipolativa", con l'intenzionale attitudine a manipolare?

Seguendo alla lettera le definizioni che hai dato, nessuna di queste sarebbe corretta. Essendo "manipolante" participio presente, una "persona manipolante" sarebbe una persona che **in quel momento** sta manipolando. Siccome invece "manipolatorio" significa "relativo alla manipolazione", nemmeno "persona manipolatrice" avrebbe senso. Per "persona manipolante" vedi risposta precedente. Infine, se "manipolativo" significa "relativo alla manipolazione" (molto simile a "manipolatorio"), non lo assocerei ad una persona.

Probabilmente limitarsi a dire "un manipolatore" rimane ancora la scelta migliore perché, oltre ad essere sicuramente corretto, non appesantisce la frase.

> Un comportamento può essere manipolatorio/manipolativo? O sarebbe
>   meglio usare questi due termini solo in giurisprudenza ("sentenze
>   manipolatorie/manipolative") o forse in campo tecnico? Non sarebbe
>   meglio dire un "comportamento manipolante"? Certo "un comportamento
>   manipolatore" non mi suona molto bene. E un "comportamento
>   manipolatorio/manipolativo" è lo stesso che un "comportamento
>   manipolante"?

Un comportamento può essere manipolatorio o manipolativo (sempre guardando le definizioni già citate). Anche "comportamento manipolante" potrebbe essere corretto in certe frasi, se la manipolazione sta avvenendo in quel momento. Come dici anche tu, sembra essere usato molto poco, quindi potrebbe essere buona idea evitare di utilizzarlo troppo liberamente.

Per "comportamento manipolatore" valgono le stesse osservazioni fatte nella prima risposta relativa alle persone. Infine, un "comportamento manipolatorio/manipolativo" è un comportamento che serve a manipolare, in generale, mentre un "comportamento manipolante" pone più l'accento sul fatto che il comportamento che sta manipolando in un preciso momento (quello in cui la persona sta pronunciando/scrivendo la frase).

Quindi riassumendo, per persone:

1. "persona manipolatrice": meglio di no, ridondante
2. "persona manipolante": persona che sta effettuando una manipolazione in un preciso istante
3. "persona manipolatoria/manipolativa": seguendo le definizoni date, parrebbe inappropriato associare questi aggettivi ad una persona

Per comportamenti:

1. "comportamento manipolatore": idem come sopra
2. "comportamento manipolante": idem come sopra
3. "comportamento manipolatorio/manipolativo": questo sì, parrebbe senza dubbio corretto

Spero di non aver dimenticato niente! Se noti errori/dimenticanze fammele pure notare, la domanda era piuttosto complicata :D

Comment: Tuttavia vi possono essere tanti motivi per cui a volte sia consigliabile adottare un aggettivo anziché un sostantivo. Per esempio quando si assegnano più attributi allo stesso sostantivo: «una persona scaltra, subdola, ingannatrice e manipolatrice». Penso che a volte conviene ignorare il vocabolario e andare ad intuito: forse questi casi sono tra quelli per cui vi è un certo grado di indeterminazione della regola, tale che in definitiva questa dipenda in larga misura dalle scelte di chi parla.

Comment: Per esempio non sono convinto che il participio presente si debba usare solo per ciò che accade in un determinato istante presente: a volte questo diventa aggettivo a sé stante. Così come una "persona attraente" è una persona **capace** di attrarre e che di norma **esercita** tale capacità sulle persone che la circondano, per una "persona manipolante" dovrebbe valere un simil principio.

Comment: @randomatlabuser sono perfettamente d'accordo. La mia risposta voleva essere precisa dal punto di vista grammaticale, poi chiaramente nella quotidianità si può essere un po' più liberali. Inoltre, attraente è anche un aggettivo, mentre manipolante non lo è, da lì ne deriva la complessità di definizioni

Comment: Grazie della risposta. È … perplimente … come l'unica differenza tra "attraente" e "manipolante" sembri essere che il primo è **diventato** un aggettivo per il largo uso che ne viene fatto mentre il secondo è ancora al rango di semplice partecipio presente.

Comment: @randomatlabuser Esattamente. Ho l'impressione che a volte i vocabolari non siano al passo con la lingua effettiva, questo parrebbe esserne un altro esempio.

Answer (score -2):

If you are english, "manipolare" means "to manipulate, to handle". 
Se sei italiano, "manipolare" significa proprio "gestire con le proprie mani, modellare".

Comment: Walid, se visiti i link nel testo della domanda vedrai che "manipolare" ha generato tanti "figli", tanti vocaboli dai vari significati, alcuni non del tutto chiari. La mia domanda verte sugli aggettivi da usare per qualificare una cosa o una persona "che manipola". La maggiore incertezza è sull'uso di "manipolatore-trice" e "manipolante": il primo sembra essere il termine più comune, con uso aggettivale che però stranamente non sembra essere riconosciuto dai dizionari; il secondo, oltre a non comparire nei dizionari, sembra anche essere poco frequente (mentre mi sarei aspettato il contrario).